# Intuition behind precalculus probability..very simple

Tags: probability

Two dice are rolled. What is the probability that only one of the dice shows a six?

So, the probability that the first dice rolls a six is (1/6)

Thus, the probability that the second dice does not roll a six is (5/6)

Hence, (1/6) * (5/6) = 5 / 36 but that is not the right answer

Moreover, how do I know if I should be multiplying or adding the values? Should I be doing (1/6) + (5/6) instead of multiplying them together? When do I do one and not the other ?

Comment: You need to add to this the probability of first non-$6$, and second $6$. Or double your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events $A$: "The first dice rolls a six" and $B$: "The second doesn't roll a six" are independents, so the event $A\cap B$: "The first dice rolls a six and the second dice doesn't roll a six" has a probability equals to $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B) = 1/6 \times 5/6 = 5/36.$$

The probability of $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$: "The first dice doesn't roll a six and the second dice rolls a six" is obviously equal to $5/36$ too.

As the two events $A\cap B$ and $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$ are mutually exclusive, the probability that exactly one of the dice shows a six is
$$
  P(A\cap B) + P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}) = 2\times \frac{5}{36} = \frac{5}{18}.
$$

Comment: Hey sorry I don't understand that symbol notation? Can we keep it to like + and multiplication at max only ? I kind of understood what you were trying to say :)

Comment: You need to calculate the product $1/6\times 5/6$ because the two rolls are independents. And as André explained you, you only calculated the probability of "the first dice rolls a six and second dice doesn't roll a six". You need to add the probability of "the first dice doesn't roll a six and second dice rolls a six".